# Syntax highlighting and code autocomplete depends on the file name?

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm 2016.2

Working with Python + Django.

When I create a file frame_form.html, there is no syntax highlighting and no code auto-completing.

If I rename the file, say,into frame_for.html, everything works.

Could you help me understand the situation?

Comment: No idea why but I am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Changing the name would highlight the file as HTML, but when I used the name I wanted then it was treated as text (in my case blog_index_page.html).

go to:

```
settings -> editor -> file types
```

Then choose "text" in the panel on the top right.

The bottom panel then shows the patters that are registered to be highlighted as text - which included the name of the file I was dealing with 'blog_index_page.html'.

I deleted this entry and it worked as expected.

(Taken from the Pycharm support forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999775-No-syntax-highlighting-for-one-html-file)